# Backup a Blog site

Tags: backup

I have set up a new SharePoint environment for learning purpose.  I have also started utilizing the O-O-T-B Blog website to create my own posts during the learning phase.

As the learning continues, I may have to reinstall SharePoint in future.  But before reinstalling, I would like to backup the Blog website and again restore it later.

I may not be interested in backing up whole SharePoint environment, but instead only the Blog website. What is the process of backing/restoring my blog site.

Comment: Alex Angas, my post shows your name below with status "Edited".  What does this mean?  I notice you are an Admin, but what is the change you have made to my post?

Comment: @kamleshrao: Directly above my name is a hyperlink stating how long ago the edit was made, and if you click on that you will see the edit. It was just to tidy up and remove unnecessary text to make it faster for people to see, process and answer your question. E.g. no need to write thanks as that's done on this site by upvoting and marking things as answered. :-) Also we already have your name on the page, etc... Any other questions please flag/tweet/e-mail! Bet regards and welcome :-)

Answer (score 5):

The two main options I would consider are:

1. Create a template with content from the Blog site.  This will give you a .stp file that can be added to the site template gallery of any new site.  This can be done completely through the UI.
2. Run the stsadm export command to do a backup of the sub-site.

Answer (score 5):

If you've created the blog as a site collection, I would recommend going with STSADM's Backup operation, using the -URL parameter to indicate that you're doing a site collection backup instead of a catastrophic backup. Here's the TechNet article on the Backup operation for more info: [STSADM's Backup Operation - TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263441.aspx)

I would recommend the Backup operation instead of the Export operation, just because its going to capture more data about your site. If you're not creating the site as a site collection, but rather a web (subsite) within a site collection, then you'll have to use the Export operation (the Backup operation can't get any more granular than a site collection).

John

Comment: If this is SharePoint 2010, the Backup-SPSite PowerShell cmdlet is an alternative to the backup stsadm operation. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748617.aspx#section1